# How can I execute an action on element only when it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to write a script that simulates a click on a certain button on page. I tried using `window.onload` but it doesn't work. It seems to me that the problem is that when my script starts executing, the element I want to interact with doesn't exist yet. How can I do that?

Here is what I tried:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('story')[0].onload = function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('story')[0].click();
    };
};
```

Comment: the onload event is only available for some DOM objects, such as window. I don't see the point having an onload event for a A or P tag for example. You may move your script at the page bottom, so that the `story` tag is present in the DOM (remove the onload thing for the `story` tag)

Comment: because elements tend to not have an onload event. What is a "story" element? Seems like something needs to trigger an event when it is set.

Comment: just curious, why don't you call the function that is triggered on story click ?

Comment: Are you adding the button dynamically or it present in the DOM from start?

Comment: @Pierre, I can't move my script to bottom because I use browser extension to add it to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `click()` in a recursive function that uses `setTimeout()`

```js
window.onload = function() {
    function findButton(){
        setTimeout(function(){
           let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('story')[0]
           if(!btn){
              findButton()
           }else{
              btn.click()
           }
        }, 300)
    }
    
    findButton()
}
```